# Google Drive Dash Plugin

Tags: plugins

What is the purpose of the Google Drive dash plugin? Is it usable in anyway and how can it be used? Am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why the negative upvote? Am new to using Ubuntu thats why am asking.

Comment: I'm just guessing but it could have something to do with Google Drive.....

Answer (score 0):

You first have to add your google account by going to the gear in the top right of the screen, then System Settings, then Online Accounts.  Just click on Google, enter your username and password, accept the policy, and you should now get Google Drive results in the Dash.

Comment: Say the google account is accessed via a school corporate email, can it still work? I have been trying to login to the Online Accounts but it does not continue.

Comment: Just tried mine and it worked.  Did you put your full address in?  For example, I have to put "user@students.college.edu" instead of just "user".  It then redirects you to your school's login page to authenticate.